# SSH warning, Help

Tags: ssh

[image]

every time I turn on my raspberry I get this warning
How can i fix this?

Comment: read the message ... it literally tells you what to do

Comment: That's poor coding on the pi OS ... "Advertencia" - obviously not English, yet the warning is in English - so while it may be true to say "it literally tells you what to do" - perhaps not everyone is fluent in english

Comment: @JaromandaX that is true, but google translate is available ... also, the OP did not say that the message is cryptic

Comment: Create an issue at https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/piwiz/issues as they've not done the national language support correctly in PiWiz.

Answer (score 3):

From a text terminal in the GUI, check you are working as user `pi` (should be in the prompt) and enter `passwd`.  You'll be asked to enter a new password, twice to confirm.  Don't loose/forget it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the password from the `System Options` menu of raspi-config

Type `sudo raspi-config`

It can also be changed from the `Raspberry Pi Configuration` Menu on the Desktop.